# Variable in Array won't work

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I've added a variable with a long sentence within an array and I have the correct syntax to separate the words. Yet when I try show array key 1,2,3,... I get the error `Undefined offset`.

Here is my example code:

```
$quote = '"'; 
$string = $quote.'asds dasddsfaf fdf
ewfejfierjfnsdafjafj sdf dwiofjwejf iosad dsfosdofjeijfmkslad f
dfsijioewjo fsdlfa'.$quote; 
$newstring = implode('", "', preg_split('/[\s]+/', $string)); 
$arrayz = array($newstring); 
echo $arrayz[2];
```

Echoing just `$newstring` gives me:
`"asds", "dasddsfaf", "fdf", "ewfejfierjfnsdafjafj", "sdf", "dwiofjwejf", "iosad", "dsfosdofjeijfmkslad", "f", "dfsijioewjo", "fsdlfa"`

Comment: `$arrayz` only has one index `[0]` as defined by your use of `array($newstring)`

Comment: You imploded it back to a comma-separated string. Always debug with something like `var_dump($newstring)` to see what you have there. You Place that string into an array `$arrayz`, which then has only one element.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski My end goal is `$arrayz = array( "asds" , "dasddsfaf" , "fdf" ........ );` I thought I did it right?

Comment: @user3395049 That's what the `preg_split()` produces. If you skip the `implode()` and everything that comes after, assign the output of `preg_split()` to an array, you will have what you intended.

Comment: removing implode will do it. You are merging the array back into a string with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over complicating things. There is no need to use `preg_split` here. Just use [**explode()**](https://www.php.net/explode). Try this:

```
$commer = '"'; 
$string = $commer.'asds dasddsfaf fdf
ewfejfierjfnsdafjafj sdf dwiofjwejf iosad dsfosdofjeijfmkslad f
dfsijioewjo fsdlfa'.$commer;

$newstring = explode(' ', $string);

print_r($newstring);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "asds
    [1] => dasddsfaf
    [2] => fdf
    [3] => ewfejfierjfnsdafjafj
    [4] => sdf
    [5] => dwiofjwejf
    [6] => iosad
    [7] => dsfosdofjeijfmkslad
    [8] => f
    [9] => dfsijioewjo
    [10] => fsdlfa"
)
```

**Edit, based on comment. This should do what you want:**

```
$commer = '"'; 
$string = 'asds dasddsfaf fdf ewfejfierjfnsdafjafj sdf dwiofjwejf iosad dsfosdofjeijfmkslad f dfsijioewjo fsdlfa'; 

$arrayz = array();
foreach(explode(' ', $string) as $word) {
    $arrayz[] = $commer . $word . $commer;
}

print_r($arrayz);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "asds"
    [1] => "dasddsfaf"
    [2] => "fdf"
    [3] => "ewfejfierjfnsdafjafj"
    [4] => "sdf"
    [5] => "dwiofjwejf"
    [6] => "iosad"
    [7] => "dsfosdofjeijfmkslad"
    [8] => "f"
    [9] => "dfsijioewjo"
    [10] => "fsdlfa"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, worked :) Is there a way to not just explode with ' ' (space), but to explode with all special characters?

Comment: You can explode based on any specific character or string. But if you you want to explode based on a range of possible characters, you'll need to use regex... so back to `preg_split('/YOUR REGEX/', $string)`...

Comment: Found a nice fix :)

http://www.phpdevtips.com/2011/07/exploding-a-string-using-multiple-delimiters-using-php/

Answer (score 1):

```
$commer = '"'; 
$string = $commer.'asds dasddsfaf fdf
ewfejfierjfnsdafjafj sdf dwiofjwejf iosad dsfosdofjeijfmkslad f
dfsijioewjo fsdlfa'.$commer; 
$arrayz = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $string); 
echo $arrayz[2];
```

It's also a good idea to use `preg_split('/[\s]+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` so you won't end up with empty entries in case there are double, leading, or trailing spaces.

Comment: I think the `$commer` is extraneous, per the OP's comment below the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned only one element in an array therefore the size of array is only 1 i.e; you can access only $arrayz[0].
Try to use in a loop until the string ends and store in concurrently.
This might solve.

Answer (score 0):

`array($var)` creates an array from another array (if `$var` is an array) or a single-element array otherwise. Since `implode()` returns a `string` from the imploded array, `array($newstring)` will create a single-element array that  is the imploded string!

Comment: I'm just explaining the `undefined offset` error you have